# Flutter override visibilty flag

Tags: flutter, dart

I've created StatelessWidget that consists of an Icon and 2 stacked buttons.

I'm using 2 methods for specifying the labels and visibility of the buttons.
I've successfully overriden the methods for labels in the child class, but for some reason the visibility is called from the super class.

What's more, in the child class I'm receiving an "the declaration isn't referenced" warning on the shouldShowFirstButton()

Any help would be most appreciated. Thanks!

Overriding the properties in child class:

```
@override
  String firstButtonTitleForStatus(UserClassStatus status) {
      return "someOverridenLabel";  // this one is called properly
    }

    @override
    bool shouldShowFirstButton() {
      return true; // this is never called (only the one from the super class)
    }
```

Super class's labels/visibility methods:

```
bool shouldShowFirstButton() {
   return false;
}

String firstButtonTitleForStatus(UserClassStatus status) {
    switch (status) {
      case UserClassStatus.unknown: ....
    return "Some super string";
}
```

Build method of super class:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    UserClassStatus status = someUserStatus;
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Center(child: classStatusIcon(status)),
        Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 8, 8, 8),
            child: Container(
              width: 100,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Visibility(
                    maintainSize: false,
                    visible: shouldShowFirstButton(),
                    child: MyFlatButton(
                        title: firstButtonTitleForStatus(status),
                        onPressed: () async {
                          handleFirstButtonPressed(
                              lesson, user, status, context);
                        }),
                  ),
                  Visibility(
                    maintainSize: false,
                    visible: shouldShowSecondButton(),
                    child: MyFlatButton(
                        title: secondButtonTitleForStatus(status),
                        onPressed: () async {
                          handleSecondButtonPressed(
                              lesson, user, status, context);
                        }),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ))
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Some cleanups and android studio and computer restarts later it started working...

Answer (score 0):

Cleanup, android studio restart, computer restart. Voila!